# Conditional Probability Calculation in Bayes Net

Tags: bayesian-network

Say I have a simple Bayes Net that appears like that in the picture and am giving the following probabilities:

$P(y|x) = 0.5$

$P(z|x)=0.4$

$P(y|\bar{x})=0.8$

$P(z|\bar{x}) = 0.9 $

[image: Bayes Net]

How would I calculate the following, or is it not possible to calculate them? I think I need to know $P(x)$ to be able to calculate them:

$P(y)$

$P(x|y \land z)$

$P(x|y)$

Answer (score 0):

> How would I calculate the following, or is it not possible to calculate them? I think I need to know P(x) to be able to calculate them:

Yes.

$P(y)=P(x)P(y\mid x)+P(\bar x)P(y\mid\bar x)$

$P(x\mid y,z) = \dfrac{P(x)P(y\mid x)P(z\mid x)}{P(x)P(y\mid x)P(z\mid x)+P(\bar x)P(y\mid\bar x)P(z\mid\bar x)}$

$P(x\mid y)=\dfrac{P(x)P(y\mid x)}{P(y)}$